# Lsyncd not working on Mac 10.9

Tags: ssh, osx, rsync

I'm attempting to use `lsyncd` to automatically move files to my local development server. My host is OSX 10.9.

SSH on the server works. I can connect using ssh from the host. I am using an SSH key to login. I want to do the same with `lsyncd` and have it use the same key.

I have installed https://github.com/markcarver/mac-ssh-askpass because OSX doesn't include `ssh-askpass` but it keeps asking for the password for `root@snapdev.com`.

I've had such a headache using `lsyncd` on Mac OSX 10.9. Google doesn't help much as the options used between the different versions of `lsyncd` have changed and articles/guides are inconsistent.

Here is my settings file:

```
settings {
        logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
        statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status",
        statusInterval = 1
}
sync {
    default.rsyncssh,
        source = "/Users/jay/Desktop/snapnames",
    host = "snapdev.com",
    targetdir = "~/public_html",
    excludeFrom = "/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.dev.exclude",
    rsync = {
        protect_args = false,
        archive = true,
        compress = false,
        whole_file = false,
    },
    ssh = {
        port = 1337,
        _extra = {"/usr/bin/ssh -l developer -p 1337 -i /Users/jay/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"}
    }
}
```

Why is it asking for a password? SSH works without a password using my key on the same host.

So confused because I am not even logging in as `root`

**Edit:** I've now switched to using `Grunt`. Too much hassle with lsyncd on OSX. I'd still like an answer though so I know where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're submitting the public version of your key instead of your private.

Try changing:

`/Users/jay/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

to

`/Users/jay/.ssh/id_rsa`